# I cannot figure out why it prints out numbers that have been removed from the list

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot figure out why my code keeps returning a value that I previously removed it from the list.

The exercise was to see if a card number is valid by testing it under some criteria.
I created a list (d1) that includes only the numbers that are >9. In the first list (doubles) I removed every value that is the d1. However the number 18 keeps printing out in the final list.

```
class Luhn:
    def __init__(self, card_num):
        self.card_num = card_num.replace(' ', '')
        self.card_num.isdigit()

    
    def valid(self):
        # double every second num
        doubles = list(map(lambda num: int(num)*2, self.card_num[1::2]))
        print(doubles)
        
        d1 = list(filter(lambda x: x>9, doubles)) # list with nums > 9
        print(d1)

        d2 = [x-9 for x in d1] # list with d1 - 9
        print(d2)

        for i in doubles:
            if i in d1:
                doubles.remove(i)
        
        doubles.extend(d2)
        
        singles = list(
            map(
                lambda num: int(num), self.card_num[0::2]
    )
)

        singles.extend(doubles) # returns the final list
        print(singles) # <--  HERE I SEE THE PROBLEM
 
        total = sum(singles)
        print(total)
        if total%10==0:
            print(f"The number {self.card_num} is valid")
        else:
            print(f"The number {self.card_num} in invalid")


c = Luhn("8569 2478 0383 3437")
c.valid()
```

OUTPUT:

```
[10, 18, 8, 16, 6, 6, 8, 14] # doubles
[10, 18, 16, 14] # d1
[1, 9, 7, 5] # d2
[8, 6, 2, 7, 0, 8, 3, 3, 18, 8, 6, 6, 8, 1, 9, 7, 5] # doubles final
105
The number 8569247803833437 in invalid
```

Comment: `for i in doubles: doubles.remove(i)` is suspect. Removing from a collection while iterating it is a bad idea. Use a list comprehension or another called to `filter`.

Comment: Also, once you get the code working, you can post it on [codereview.se] to get suggestions (provided the code works, and some context about the code is given).

Comment: I changed it to this: doubles = list(filter(lambda x: not x, d1)). I see if it works and i;ll post the final  code! Thank you!

Comment: it doesn't work. Or I can't make it work. It returns an error "'generator' object is not callable" . I filter with lambda then and it gives me a wrong sum.